# ReGex Phone No Format in Philippines

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to match exactly the following format:

```
+639201112222
  09201112222
```

and this is all Ive tried so far:

```
(\+63|0)?\d{10}
```

the problem is that it match `2920111222` in `29201112222`. How can i create a pattern that will match only the formats below?

```
+63XXXXXXXXXX 
  0XXXXXXXXXX
```

`+63 or 0` plus `10 digit number` only

where `X` are all digits from `0-9`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do:

```
((\+63)|0)\d{10}
```

Comment: It works! thank you. Sir why is `+63` enclose with parenthesis and `?` is removed?

Comment: because 63|0 means 6 followed by either 3 or 0

Comment: @DerekFloss, And the question mark makes the part before it optional, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

A regex for various phone number combinations (just quickly used rubular.com for this):

```
/(^0|[89]\d{2}-\d{3}\-?\d{4}$)|(^0|[89]\d{2}\d{3}\d{4}$)|(^63[89]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$)|(^63[89]\d{2}\d{3}\d{4}$)|(^[+]63[89]\d{2}\d{3}\d{4}$)|(^[+]63[89]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$)/
```

Validates:

```
0917-411-1111
0917-4111111
917-411-1111
9174111111
+63917-411-1111
63917-894-3454
639172342345
+639174111111
```

Here's a solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/kZMRx/